# How to terminate shell script after a specified time

Tags: shell, cron, ksh

I have a shell script that checks a file state.txt, deletes fit.bin if state.txt is empty.
I cron this at 2am, I will want the script to stop by 8am irrespective of the value of state.txt, any ideas?

```
#!/usr/bin/ksh


while true; do


if [[ -s ~/state.txt ]] ; then

echo

else

rm ~/fit.bin

exit

fi ;


sleep 961

done

exit
```

Comment: Create another cronjob that runs 8am and stop this.

Comment: you need to loop and delete the file every 961 second form 2am to 8am. Is 961 arbitrary or is there another meaning ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a "model":

```
#!/bin/bash

while true
do
    NOW=`date '+%H%M'`
    echo "Time is now: $NOW"
    sleep 3
    if [ $NOW -ge 800 ]
    then
        echo "Bye bye!"
        exit 0
    fi
done
```

Answer (score 0):

```
#!/bin/bash
while [ $( date '+%H%M' ) -lt 800 ]
 do
   [ -s "~/state.txt" ] && rm ~/fit.bin

   sleep 961
 done
```